# Remove old light box with a stud and nut anchor

Tags: junction-box, old-house

I read a post asking this question, but there is no answer for actually removing the box.  I do want to remove the box to install a retrofit recessed LED light.  My bungalow was built in 1952.  All ceiling light box has this stud and nut anchor.  There is also one on a vertical wall, so the stud is not necessarily for load bearing.  Please advise me on the construction of this box, and how to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These hangers were typically used in ceilings where they wanted the light to be somewhere which required space or location between joists. The bracket is typically nailed to both opposing studs or usually under the plaster or drywall.

You could cut it with a hacksaw and move it out of the way. Or for more work, cut a separate hole for the recessed light and then patch the old hole from behind.

You mentioned "retrofit". Retrofit usually means a prior recessed light fixture, which this is not.

Comment: The stud is about 1/2" dia. If the bracket is compatible, it would be quite thick as well.  Just wonder whether it is easy to cut.  Unless every ceiling outlet box (and a wall light box) was planned to go with a heavy chandelier, it would be a waste of material.  The two boxes I am trying to remove are in the ceiling of a corridor and a vertical wall, and are probably not planned for heavy loads.  I already did what you suggested of cutting an adjacent hole for the one on the vertical wall, and put a 'retrofit' recessed LED light there.  Do you have a picture of the bracket?

Comment: Suppose the octagonal box is kept in place by the nut screwed tight to the stud, how do I remove the octagonal box after unscrewing the nut?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It is the plaster around the edge of the box that is preventing it to come out.  Once I removed the nut and chiseled away the plaster around the box, it came out readily.  I then had to saw off the 1/8" hang bar.